# Submit two forms with one submit button

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I have two XHTML forms (below). I am looking for a way to submit the two forms with one submit button.

First Form Below

```
<form method= "post" action= "forum_add_111438076.xhtml" >
<input type= "hidden" name="d_token" value="2ab5b36d7d0e5f9fee88cc9a67553db6" />First 
Name:<br/><input type="text" name="meno" maxlength="20"/>
<br/>Last Name:<br/><input type="text" name="text" maxlength="20000"/>
<br/><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
```

Second Form

```
<form method="post" action="forum_add_111438075.xhtml" >
<input type="hidden" name="d_token" value="d0cb19bc6b0d162a11431213976206b8" />
Phone Number:<br/><input type="text" name="meno" maxlength="20"/>
<br/>Address:<br/><input type="text" name="text" maxlength="20000"/>
<br/><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
```

Each form above has its own submit button, but I want to use only one submit button.

Comment: You're either going to need to use javascript, or add another submit button.

Comment: Why would you not simply condense them both into a single form?

Comment: How can I make it to a single form

Comment: uh, get rid of the second form declaration and the first close form tab.  Bang.  One form.

Comment: @user3909617 - no real idea on what you'd need to wire-up without seeing the two xhtml pages that they submit to. I do notice that they each use the same field names, and different targets. They also use different values for the d_token field. It could well be messy. JS and Ajax would be the cleanest/easiest way to solve your problem - simply submit them both one after the other, as `ktzhang` suggests .

Comment: You can use JavaScript to make a submit button submit another form, letting it then do its own job. With plain HTML, it’s impossible. But the whole idea is odd, counter-intuitive, and leads to poor usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simultaneously submit two forms at once. (like one webpage cannot go to two)
One way around this would be to use Ajax and submit the forms one after another.

Some Example Code. (using jQuery)

HTML

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <form id="form1">
        <input type= "hidden" name="d_token" value="2ab5b36d7d0e5f9fee88cc9a67553db6"  />First Name:<br/><input type="text" name="meno" maxlength="20"/>
    <br/>Last Name:<br/><input type="text" name="text" maxlength="20000"/>
    <br/></form>

    <form id="form2">
    <input type="hidden" name="d_token" value="d0cb19bc6b0d162a11431213976206b8" />
    Phone Number:<br/><input type="text" name="meno" maxlength="20"/>
    <br/>Address:<br/><input type="text" name="text" maxlength="20000"/>
    <br/></form>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="submitAction()" />
```

Javascript

```
submitAction() {
    $.post('forum_add_111438076.xhtml', $('#form1').serialize())
    $.post('forum_add_111438075.xhtml', $('#form2').serialize())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exaclty possible to submit two forms at once to two different places.
The best thing you can do, if you require seperate processing, is to use your receiving page to gather the secondary form post, and send that along to the secondary processing page.  PHP using CURL is perfect for something like that.

Comment: What if a javascript is introduce so that when I click the second submit button , the first button will be automatically clicked and the data submited and I will be redirected to the page on second form   . HELP

Comment: So you want to load the page `..8075.xhtml` and the page `..8076.xhtml`, at the same time?

Answer (score -1):

If you use the get or an ajax function it will allow you to know when the first or second form is completed. Using the get you would use `.done`   if you use ajax you will use the `.success` Once your first form has completed the submission, you can then submit your other form as shown below.

```
//Submit your First form
 $.get("postOne").done(function(){

//When your first form is completed you can then submit your second form.
    $.get("postTwo").done(function(){

    });

});
```

Comment: You need to provide a bit more explanation.